# Include a return handler in async call in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm experimenting with async calls but I'm a little lost.  The `print(json)` in the `viewDidLoad` outputs an empty dictionary, but the one within the function prints correctly.  This is unsurprising; it gets to that print before the async is completed.  I can't figure out how to fix it; I tried putting the return within the completion handler, but I got an error that `Unexpected non-void return value in void function`.  I tried changing the completion handler to expect a return value, but either that's not the right approach or I was doing it wrong.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let json = getJson("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=WashingtonDC&sensor=false")
        print(json)
    }

    func getJson(url: String) -> AnyObject {
        var json:AnyObject = [:]
        let urlPath = NSURL(string: url)
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: urlPath!)
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            } else {
                do {
                    json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                    print(json)
                } catch {
                    print("json error")
                }

            }
        })
        task.resume()
        return json
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note:  I feel like I didn't really structure the setup of the json variable correctly, so any feedback there is also helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a completion handler based interface to your async API.

```
func getJson(url: String, completion : (success: Bool, json: AnyObject? ) ->Void ) -> Void {
        var json:AnyObject = [:]
        let urlPath = NSURL(string: url)
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: urlPath!)
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            } else {
                do {
                    json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                    print(json)
//Call the completion handler here:
completion(success : true, json :json )
                  } catch {
                    print("json error")
completion(success : false, json :nil )

                }

            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Now you call call this API as follows-

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       getJson("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=WashingtonDC&sensor=false") { (success, json) -> Void in 
        if success {
          if let json = json {
            print(json)
         }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I tried to edit this myself but it was rejected:  In your first line the completion handler says "result" but later on you use "success".  Is that intentional or an error?  In other news, your code works great but I am having trouble understanding it.  I looked up completion handlers but was left more confused than before (the syntax alone confuses me a lot).  Any clarification you (or anyone) could provide would be a big help!

Comment: Also:  `completion(success : false, son :nil )` should be `json: nil`.  Edit is too small for me to fix the typo.

Comment: @thumbtackthief thanks for pointing, I have edited. They were all typos as I spontaneously typed in the answer. Hope its all good now.